# Is it normal to have a long list of arguments in the constructor of a Presenter class?

Tags: tdd, dependency-injection, c#-2.0, domain-driven-design, mvp

Warning acronym overload approaching!!! I'm doing TDD and DDD with an MVP passive view pattern and DI. I'm finding myself adding dependency after dependency to the constructor of my presenter class as I write each new test. Most are domain objects. I'm using factories for dependency injection though I will likely be moving to an IoC container eventually.

When using constructor injection (as apposed to property injection) its easy to see where your dependencies are. A large number of dependencies is usually an indicator that a class has too much responsibility but in the case of a presenter, I fail to see how to avoid this.

I've thought of wrapping all the domain objects into a single "Domain" class which would act as a middle man but I have this gut feeling that I'd only be moving the problem instead of fixing it.

Am I missing something or is this unavoidable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only use DI on the Constructor if I need something to be there from the start. Otherwise I use properties and have lazy loading for the other items. For TDD/DI as long as you can inject the item when you need it you don't need to add it to your constructor.

I recommend always following the Law of Demeter and not following the DI myth of everything needs to be in the constructor. Misko Hevery (Agile Coach at Google) describes it well on his blog http://misko.hevery.com/2008/10/21/dependency-injection-myth-reference-passing/

Answer (score 1):

Often a large number of arguments to a method (constructor, function, etc) is a code smell. It can be hard to understand what all the arguments are. This is especially the case if you have large numbers of arguments of the same type. It is very easy for them to get confused which can introduce subtle bugs.

The refactoring is called "Introduce Parameter Object". Whether that's really a domain object or not, it is basically a data transfer object that minimizes the number of parameters passed to a method and gives them a bit more context.

Answer (score 0):

Having a [Layer Supertype](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/layerSupertype.html) might not be a bad idea, but I think your code smell might be indicating something else.  Geofflane mentioned the refactor pattern, [Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).  While it's a good pattern for this sort of problem, I'm not entirely sure it's the way to go for this situation.

Question:  Why are you passing in Domain Model objects to the constructor?

There is such a thing as having *too much* abstraction.  If there's one solid layer of code you should be able to trust, it's your [Domain Model](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html).  You don't need to reference 3 IEntity objects when you're dealing with Customer, Vendor, and Product classes if those are part of your basic Domain Model and you don't necessarily need polymorphism.

My advice: Pass in application and domain *services*.  Trust your Domain Model.

**EDIT:**

Re-reading the problem when it's not horribly late at night, I realize your "Domain class" is already the Introduce Parameter Object refactoring and not, in fact, a Layer Supertype, as I thought at 3AM.

I also realize that perhaps you need to reference the Model objects in the application code, outside the Presenter.  Perhaps you're doing some initial setup of your Model objects before passing them in to the Presenter.  If this is the case, your "Domain class" idea might be best.  If there is some initial setup, when moving to an IoC, you'll want to look at something like [Factory Support](http://castleproject.org/container/facilities/trunk/factory/index.html) in Castle Windsor.  (Other IoC containers have similar concepts.)